# How to include a .txt file content inside the Latex file

Tags: pdftex

How to include a .txt file contents inside a Latex file so that the generated PDF from the Latex file should record the contents of the .txt file

\verbatiminput{../../foo.txt} is not working. Doing so causes the compiler break at that line in .tex file.

Please show me a way how I can include a .txt file inside Latex so that my generated PDF file has the contents of the .txt file

Comment: If i use the below lines of code inside the .tex file

Comment: \input{aaa.txt} % your text file


\textbf{But if you want to reproduce your text as it is:}
{\obeylines\obeyspaces
\texttt{
\input{aaa.txt}
}}

Comment: I got errors like :::Y:\frdcc_motorcontrol\project\asm_bk\output\ForAppl_Description.txt:20: Missing
 $ inserted where ForAppl_Description.txt is the file i wish to paste in the generated .pdf

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Please, instead of posting comments, edit your original post to add any relevant elements to your question.

Comment: don't just post a one line fragment and say "it is not working" post a test document and show exactly the error that you got. Did you define `\verbatiminput` eg with the `verbatim` package? It is not defined in latex by default.

Comment: I am sorry I will improve this behavior on posting questions with proper information. Yes I have included verbatim package and while using \verbatiminput{file.txt} it is not working There is no error in command window but the compiler is breaking the execution

Comment: What is the name of the file?  You've said "foo.txt" and "file.txt", but the error message you copied talked about "ForAppl_Description.txt".  If the latter, it could be the underscore messing things up.  Can you remove that?  Otherwise, please copy and paste the error into you question body, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

one can use `\usepackage{listings}`.

And when you want to input your file use.

`\lstinputlisting[caption=myfile.txt]{file.txt}`.

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{file.txt}
first line
second line
third line
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
 
\textbf{Title}
 
\lstinputlisting[caption=myfile.txt]{file.txt}

 that's it.

\end{document}
```